# error:are you missing using directive or a assembly reference?

Tags: c#

I'm new to visual c#(window forms). I'm working on a project which consists of three forms. From1 accesses form2 and form3.Form2 worked well and good. But Form3 is giving some problem. I created form3, added three picture boxes to it and accessed from form1. Now if I run the code I'm getting the error

> Error  3   'gp.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'label1_Click' and no extension method 'label1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'gp.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error is pointed in form1.designer.cs at this line,

```
this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
```

without form3 no errors.
when i add form3 im getting these kind of errors.
though form3.designer is existing why its pointing to form1.designer?

```
namespace gp
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and the in form1 im accessing form3 as

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3(name);
frm3.Show();
```

in form2 i got similar problem.i solved it by changing the name of namespace but its not working with form3. Anyone knows the answer let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to Form3 and see if it works:

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

You double clicked the Label and it added an event for Click, which you probably deleted from code behind at some point

Comment: They will not be able to see that event from Form1 because it is 'private' - or maybe I have misunderstood the problem they are having.

Comment: I have done the same mistake which u mentioned.Anyway adding that again was not working because it can only be system generated and cannot be done manually.So i deleted the form1 and created it again.Now its working properly.Thank you...